# Merging function of two linkedlist is not working

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct listNode *listPointer;

struct listNode{
    int data;
    listPointer link;
};

int boolean_search(listPointer f, int q) {
    listPointer t = f;
    while(t){

        if(q == t->data){
            return 1;
        }         
       t = t ->link;
    }
    return 0;
}
listPointer elem_search(listPointer f, int q) {
    listPointer t = (listPointer) malloc(sizeof(listPointer));
    t->data = -1;
    t->link =f;
    while(t){

        if(q == t->data){
            //printf("Match Found");
            return t;
        }         
       t = t ->link;
    }
    return NULL;
}
void del_num(listPointer f, int q) {
    listPointer temp = elem_search(f, q), z;
    if(temp) {
    z=temp;
    temp = temp->link;
    free(z);
    }
}

void delete_trial(listPointer x,int num) {
    del_num(x, num);
}

listPointer create(int start, int finish)
{
    int i = 0, flag = 1;
    listPointer created = (listPointer) malloc(sizeof(listPointer)), st = NULL;

    for( i = start; i < finish; i++)
    {
        listPointer temp = (listPointer) malloc(sizeof(listPointer));
        int num = rand() % 50;
        //printf("%d",search(st, num));
        if(flag == 1 && num !=0) {
            temp->data = num;
            temp->link = NULL;
            created = temp;
            st = created;
            flag = 0;

        } else if(!boolean_search(st, num) && num !=0)
        {
            //printf("I am here");
            temp->data = num;
            temp->link = NULL;
            created->link = temp;
            created = temp;
        }
    }
    return st;
}

void display(listPointer start){
    listPointer temp = start;
    printf("\nContents of given pointer : ");
    while(temp){
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}

int count_list( listPointer x) {
    listPointer y =x;
    int count = 0;
    while(y) {
        count ++;
        y = y->link;
    }
    return count;
}
int count_non_zero(listPointer x) {
    listPointer y =x;
    int count = 0;
    while(y) {
        if(y->data != 0 )count ++;
        y = y->link;
    }
    return count;
}
int scan_least_no(listPointer x){
    int least = x->data, z;
    listPointer y = x;
    while(y)
    {
        z = y->data;
        if(( z < least) && z != 0){
            least = z;
        }
        y = y->link;
    }
    return least;
}
listPointer scan_least_ptr(listPointer x){
    int least = x->data, z;
    listPointer y = x, f = x;
    while(y)
    {
        z = y->data;
        if(( z < least) && z != 0){
            least = z;
            f = y;
        }
        y = y->link;
    }

    return f;
}

listPointer merge_asc(listPointer a, listPointer b) {
    listPointer result = (listPointer) malloc(sizeof(listPointer));
    result->data = -1;
    result ->link = NULL;

    int countA = count_non_zero(a), countB = count_non_zero(b), flag =0;//flag 0 for A, flag 1 for B
    int leastNum = 0, leastNumA = 0, leastNumB = 0; 

    listPointer result_start = result, copyA = a, copyB =b;

    printf("Count of listA : %d, listB : %d", countA, countB);
    //scanning least element
    //compare every element to existing ,the least one in connected to the link of that node


    while((countA + countB) != 0)
    {
        printf("Stuck in here");
        if(countA > 0)
        {
            //if least from here flag 0
            leastNumA = scan_least_no(copyA); 

        } else if(countB > 0)
        {
            //if least from here flag 1
            leastNumB = scan_least_no(copyA);
        }
        if(leastNumA < leastNumB)
        {
            flag = 0;
            leastNum = leastNumA;
        } else {
            flag =1;
            leastNum = leastNumB;
        }


        if(flag == 0)
        {
            result ->link = elem_search(copyA, leastNum);
            result = result ->link;
            delete_trial(a, leastNum); 
        }else if(flag == 1){
            result ->link = elem_search(copyB, leastNum);
            result = result ->link;
            delete_trial(b, leastNum);
        }
        countA = count_non_zero(copyA);
        countB = count_non_zero(copyB);
    }

    printf("\nMerged Pointer : ");
    display(result_start);
    return result_start;
}


int main()
{
    listPointer a = create(10,20), b = create(1, 30), c;
    display(a);
    display(b);
    c = merge_asc(a, b);
    display(c);
    return 0;
}
```

This program takes two linked lists and makes a new linked list from the existing linked lists.
Constraints: elements should be in ascending order, new linked list should use the existing nodes

Q: "let x = x1,x2, x3, xn and y = y1, y2, y3, yn be two linked lists. Write a program to merge the two lists together to form a  new linked list **z** in which nodes are in ascending order. Following the merge x,y do not exist as individual lists. Each node initially in x ad y is now in z".

I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my **merge_asc** function because output is stuck "Contents of given pointer : 33 36 27 15 43 35 42 49 21 "
I am thinking that in delete function, due to the free function there is something going on that I didn't considered in my program.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong or what is the solution of it and what approach I should take in these situations?

I have tested every other function and they are working fine.
I am using ubuntu 14.04 and gcc4.8.4

Comment: Do you want to make new nodes or use the current nodes?  aka are the input lists left unchanged

Comment: also are you assuming the input lists are sorted?

Comment: @pwilmot input list is not sorted, it is randomly generated and program is using the existing data nodes to link in resulting listPointer

Comment: I don't understand that one: *new linked list should use the existing nodes*

Comment: @Elyasin I meant you shouldn't create a new linked list by copying the existing the data values in the list. You should use the existing nodes within the new node. for example : if the two lists are a (5) -> b( 10) -> c(3) and p(9) -> q (2) -> r(11)-> s(1); then approach of creating the new list shouldn't be extracting the values and creating a new list with new nodes. It should be s(1)->q(2)->c(3)->a(5)->p(9)->b(10)->r(11)

Comment: So basically pointer address arithmetic?

Comment: @Elyasin sorry to say but I don't know the exact technical term

Comment: `listPointer t = (listPointer) malloc(sizeof(listPointer));` You are allocating a pointer here, and store its address in a pointer (whisch has the wrong type, BTW). You must come from a JAVA world ... Best advice I can give you at this moment is to avoid typedeffing pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Given two unsorted lists

```
2 -> 7 -> 1
5 -> 3 -> 4
```

If the input lists were sorted then you would use a merge sort and could do it in linear time but since these are unsorted lists you will need to take atleast NlogN time.  I would advise starting by sorting one of the input lists and then doing an insertion sort with the elements of the other list.

so start by sorting the first list to get

```
1 -> 2 -> 7
```

then run an insertion sort with the other list to get

```
1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 7
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 7
```

Comment: thanks for the insight, could you help me with the code I have written in the question

Comment: Maybe it is not even necessary to sort one list beforehand. Simply use insertion sort into the new linked list. Insert (sort) first list elements, then insert (sort) second list elements.